# How do I remove the Python 2.7 I installed and roll back to 2.6?

Tags: 10.04, python

by a series of errors, Python 2.7 was installed over 2.6 within Ubuntu 10.04. Both appear to be working, however many things are not (yolk, freenx, easy_install, pip, etc).

I believe the issue is that 2.7 is now seen as the default for python, but the OS is still trying to use 2.6. For example, when I try and run yolk, I get:

```
user@linuxbox:/usr/local/lib$ yolk -l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/yolk", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2735, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 690, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: yolk==0.4.3
```

Is there a way to rip 2.7 out, and revert everything back to 2.6?

Answer (score 2):

After a long search I found something that appears to have worked:

```
sudo ln -f /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python
```